# Cannot authenticate with Yahoo OAuth

Tags: yahoo-oauth

I'm trying to authorize with Yahoo using a link like this:

> `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=dj0yJmk9ZHNUWExxZmhHckFDJmQ9WVdrOVdsQmtNa3BKTlRZbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD03MA--&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flastlink.com%2Fauthorize&response_type=code`

However it responds with:

> Please check the redirect URI in your request and submit again

I tried to search for this topic on ydn forums but they seems to be broken.

Answer (score 2):

The domain of the `redirect_uri` has to be the same as the callback domain for the YDN App.

I can get a code using `redirect_uri=oob`:

> `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=dj0yJmk9ZHNUWExxZmhHckFDJmQ9WVdrOVdsQmtNa3BKTlRZbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD03MA--&redirect_uri=oob&response_type=code`

Comment: i cant quite get the logic behind that: why the 'oob' value seems to be valid

Comment: My RP always appends the port number to the hostname in the redirect_uri and yahoo doesn't allow you to put a portname in that value.  That's a problem.